# sql query within python - insert multiple dictionaries' values to separate table columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a list of dictionaries that all cointain 2 key:value pairs (keys are always the same: 'symbol' & 'name'). I need to write an SQL query within python in order insert all the values from the 1st pair within a dictionary to the first column of the table and the values of the 2nd pair to the second column of the same table. I've tried this so far:

```
for coin in coins:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp_coins (symbol, name) VALUES (%s, %s)",
               coin['symbol'], coin['name'])
```

But it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were
> given

I've also tried inserting values separately in one column and then the other with the following code:

```
for coin in coins:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp_coins (symbol) VALUES (%s)",
                   coin['symbol'])
```

But then it gives me another error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Could anyone, please, help me with the correct query for this?

Comment: Try ```cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp_coin VALUES (%s,%s)",(str(coin['symbol]),str(coin['name'])))```

Comment: I suggest to remove the column names - ```(symbol)```,```(symbol,name)```

Comment: Please provide the dictionary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you first example is almost correct. Only problem should be, that all values for substitution in you SQL should passed as single iterable.

```py
for coin in coins:
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO temp_coins (symbol, name) VALUES (%s, %s)",
        (coin['symbol'], coin['name']),
    )
```

Comment: I leaves me with a different error message now:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 327455: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: What version of python do you use? PY2 or PY3?

Comment: I'm using python3

Comment: Can you confirm that `coin['symbol']` and `coin['name']` are both `str` type and not `bytes`?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that certain values contain numbers in them? All of them are formatted as strings though.

Comment: As long as they are `str` type, it should not be relevant. I suggest you create new question with example of `coin` and full traceback this raises. Because this seems to be different problem to your original question.

Comment: I reloaded the data to dictionaries (as I'm retrieving it from an API service) and then it worked fine. Thank you so much @gjask!